# Trouble appending array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, append, push

I'm a learning to program and I can't seem to figure out how to append the following array.  Here's a snippet.

```
<?php
$dir = "./media/";

if($dh = opendir($dir))
{
    while(false != ($file = readdir($dh)))
    {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
        $pathinfo = $pathinfo['filename'];


        $mp3 = "http://localhost/media/" . $file;


        $Obj1 = ["title=" => $pathinfo,
                "artist=" => "artist1",
                "mp3=" => $mp3];

        $Obj2 = append($Obj1);
   }
   }

closedir($dh);
}
?>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking [**for these?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Why did you overwrite my edit?

Comment: I didn't mean to.  I just noticed I didn't include the <?php and the $dir variable at the top.

Comment: I didn't mean to.  I just noticed I forgot the <?php and $dir variable at the top.

Comment: Ok. Well, I re-indented the last 2 lines that you missed. All code needs the minimum of 4 spaces for proper indent.

Comment: I was just creating a second Object to append the data into.  I assume i could probably do this with $Obj1.

Comment: @EngiNeer732 `$Obj1` is an array, not an object. And there is no function `append()` in PHP. So, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok.  I changed append($Obj1) to array_push($Obj1) and added a var_dump($Obj2).  The dump returns NULL and the error reporting gives me "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be an array.  Outside of the loop I have defined the array as such.

    $Obj2 = array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dir = "./media/";
// Always initialize your array
$array = array();
if ( $dh = opendir($dir) ) {
    while ( false != ( $file = readdir($dh) ) ) {
        if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) {

            $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
            $pathinfo = $pathinfo['filename'];


            $mp3 = "http://localhost/media/" . $file;

            // Don't do silly things like putting "=" in every key
            $thisArray = array(
                'title' => $pathinfo,
                'artist' => 'artist1',
                'mp3' => $mp3
            );
            $array[] = $thisArray;
            // Or $array += $thisArray;
        }
   }

    closedir($dh);
}
```